# Add items to edittext Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image: Item "Fred L."]

How could I put an item like "Fred L." in an EditText the way Messenger is doing ?
I don't have any code to show since I have no idea on how to do it.

Comment: They're  called chips https://github.com/DoodleScheduling/android-material-chips

Answer (score 0):

Its a customized TextView with a Rounded style, padding and a background.

Comment: It's more commonly referred to as a chip

Comment: I know it is but how can I add it to the EditText and keep typing ?

Comment: You can add it programmatically in you Classes code e.g. new TextView. You now then add this RelativeLayout Parameter to the EditText toRightOf the newly created TextView.